# R - How to collapse rows of dataframe taking the max of each column for each unique id

Tags: r

What I have is a large data frame wherein most of the unique ids are a single row; however, there are some rows that have duplicate ids because of multiple binary diagnoses. What I would like is to collapse each duplicated id into one id and take the max of each column. The non-duplicated rows would stay the same.

Suppose I have this df

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "6"),
             age = c(50, 50, 45, 35, 75, 37, 33, 33),
             weight = c(75, 75, 80, 100, 82, 90, 71, 71),
             diagnosis1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
             diagnosis2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
             diagnosis3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

  id age weight diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3
1  1  50     75          1          0          0
2  1  50     75          0          0          1
3  2  45     80          0          0          1
4  3  35    100          1          0          0
5  4  75     82          0          1          0
6  5  37     90          0          0          0
7  6  33     71          1          0          0
8  6  33     71          0          1          0
```

I'm hoping to achieve this output:

```
> df

  id age weight diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3
1  1  50     75          1          0          1
2  2  45     80          0          0          1
3  3  35    100          1          0          0
4  4  75     82          0          1          0
5  5  37     90          0          0          0
6  6  33     71          1          1          0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `dplyr` with `group_by` and `summarize_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize_all(max)
```

This code will look at every unique value of `id` and take the max value for all the other columns.

Comment: That did it. I was trying something overly complicated with my summarize_all() call. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate` to get the `max` per group.

```
aggregate(df[,-1], list(id=df[,1]), max)
#  id age weight diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3
#1  1  50     75          1          0          1
#2  2  45     80          0          0          1
#3  3  35    100          1          0          0
#4  4  75     82          0          1          0
#5  5  37     90          0          0          0
#6  6  33     71          1          1          0
```

Or even shorter as commented by @d.b

```
aggregate(. ~ id, df, max)
```

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ id, df, max)`